# Query data on Firestore and follow the document reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Playlists collection (contains a Video ref.)

[image]

Videos collection

[image]

Query it

```
const queryRef = firestore.collection('playlists').where('machines', 'array-contains', id)
const snapshot = await queryRef.get()
```

Transform data into array of videos

```
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  // console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  const playlist = doc.data() as Playlist
  arr.push(...playlist.videos)
});
```

Which result into

```
[
   {
      "_firestore":{
         "projectId":"my-app"
      },
      "_path":{
         "segments":[
            "videos",
            "BigBuckBunny"
         ]
      },
      "_converter":{
         
      }
   }
]
```

What I want is:

The video document has a property `url`; I want to build an array of these URLs using Video reference.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you need to fetch the videos docs with the `get()` method. And since you want to execute an undetermined number of calls to the asynchronous `get()` method in parallel, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
const queryRef = firestore.collection('playlists').where('machines', 'array-contains', id)
const snapshot = await queryRef.get()

const promises = [];
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const videosRefArray = doc.data().videos;  // Array of DocumentReferences
    videosRefArray.forEach(videoRef => {
        promises.push(videoRef.get())
    })
});

const docSnapshotsArray = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one question, by using Promise.all, the final array, docSnapshotsArray, will be in any order or it will be in the same order of the videos refs?

Comment: Good question, it will be in the same order than the `promises` Array. The MDN documentation says "The fulfillment value is an array of fulfillment values, in the order of the promises passed, regardless of completion order."